# Javascript each() function remove link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, each

I've got a website under prestashop, and my dropdown menu has different categories that are all clickable.  I would like to remove the links from the "Marques" and "Les Gammes" categories and leave just the text. I'm using the `each()` function to select all my categories, but this returns an array within the `li` and the `ul` inside the `li`.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Retiixx/orvrj7qs/4).

Here is the js code:

```
$('jms-mega-menu').ready(function () {
// Get each div
$('.notlink').each(function () {
    // Get the content
    var str = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(str);
 });
});
```

And here is a sample of my html code. You can find the full code on the fiddle.

```
<ul jms-mega-menu>
 <div>
  ...
   <ul class="mega-nav level1">
    <li class=" haschild group notlink"><a id="item-8" href="#">Marques</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a id="item-9" href="#">Apple</a></li>
      <li><a id="item-10" href="#">Samsung</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
   ...
```

Comment: Do you mean `'.notlink a:first'` to get the first link text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be use `unwrap` to remove the `a` tag from around the text.  Note the use of `.notlink > a` to only affect anchors that are direct children of the `.notlink` and not the nested lists:

```
$('.notlink > a').contents().unwrap();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orvrj7qs/5/

Another option which may be a bit more extensible would be to use `replaceWith`, which would allow you to make additional modifications to the text if needed:

```
$('.notlink > a').replaceWith(function(){
    return $(this).text();   
});
```

In this case, we simply replace the anchor with just the text within the anchor.

http://jsfiddle.net/orvrj7qs/6/

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot, and so quick. Thank you. I didn't know the unwrap method.
Is there a SOLVED tag to add to my question ? Or I have to put it manually ?

Comment: Happy to help.  On SO, you mark your question as "solved" by accepting an answer.  You can see a description of how this works here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work